# Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

hi there i am a student and practicing how to place the like box plugging code in simple html using the notepad,
here is the simple code i write with the like box plugging code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Febitesblog&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=590" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </body>
 </html>
```

and when i try to execute in browser it says:
This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address:

```
file://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Febitesblog&width=292&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=590
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found
```

hope guys it will fix my problem thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

It's failing because the `//` in that is protocol relative meaning it loads the link/photo/like box/whatever using the same protocol used to access the page itself.

- When accessing the page over HTTP (`http://`), the Like Box will be included over HTTP
- When accessing the page over HTTPS (`https://`), the Like Box will be included over HTTPS

You're accessing a file on localhost, via the file protocol (`file://`) - which means it tries to include the Like box the same way, which is not valid since there isn't a file on your machine called 'www.facebook.com`

Use `<iframe src="https://...` now, and change it back to `<ifame src=//...` when you're uploading to your server

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox...
```

should be...

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox...
```