# Open Google directions into div from Map marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Im trying to open directions from a marker click on google maps in a div rather than in a new window.

Currently I can open the direction in a new window but I want to open them in an iframe in a div that will be displayed when a marker is clicked.

I cant use a static src url on the iframe because I use different URL for the different markers on the map.

Any help would be great, this is what I have so far.

```
  var depots = [
  ['Barnsley', 53.572664, -1.455800, 11, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=53.572664,-1.455800&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Birmingham', 52.359018, -1.938033, 10, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=52.359018,-1.938033&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Brentwood', 51.576452, 0.278843, 9, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=51.576452,0.278843&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Bristol', 51.501280, -2.366513, 8, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=51.501280,-2.366513&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Cambridge', 52.184396, -0.064012, 7, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=52.184396,-0.064012&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Edinburgh', 56.129890, -3.390296, 6, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=56.129890,-3.390296&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Gatwick', 51.152422, -0.216219, 5, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=51.152422,-0.216219&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Glasgow', 55.927129, -4.467189, 4, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=55.927129,-4.467189&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Heathrow', 51.508121, -0.387525, 3, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=51.508121,-0.387525&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Manchester', 53.220004, -2.414895, 2, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=53.220004,-2.414895&directionsmode=driving'],
  ['Southampton', 50.959088, -1.345449, 1, 'http://maps.google.com/?daddr=50.959088,-1.345449&directionsmode=driving'],


  ];
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var depot = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(depot[1], depot[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: depot[0],
        zIndex: depot[3],
        url: depot[4]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        document.getElementById('direction').style.display = "";
        window.location.href = this.url;
    });
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="directionholder">
    <iframe id="directioniframe" frameborder="0" > </iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried making a var of this.url and setting that in the function but no luck

```
var URLis = this.url;
document.getElementById('directioniframe').src = " URLis ";
```

Comment: remove quotes from "URLis" and use URLis in your last line of code and try.

Comment: I get a :( The file or directory could not be found. in my iframe

Comment: What do you have in "locations"? Can you post here?

Comment: edited question with depot var

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to split it in a function?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', direction);
function direction(evt)
{
   document.getElementById('directioniframe').src = this.url;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that no jou, where should I put the URLis var? still inside the function?

Comment: You may also set an attribute to the marker like "depotIndex",
reading it in the sub function and build your url dinamically reading data from depot array

Comment: Im using the URL's so that when the marker is tapped on it has end location in the map. Im not sure what you mean by creating a depotindex?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example how it should be done: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3550/

I have pasted the code which should be inside the loop. Have a look at it.

JS:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    url:'http://jsfiddle.net'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    //document.getElementById('direction').style.display = "";
    var win = window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
});
```

Regarding the error you mentioned in the comments, refer this answer:[Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852850/error-6-neterr-file-not-found-the-file-or-directory-could-not-be-found)

The error must be due to the protocol issue. Also note that the iframe will not load because of the `same origin policy` . Read more here : http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: So, This isnt possible due to to being to different domains?

Comment: If you want to read more about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Hmm ok, can you suggest a work around? It is for a web app that will allow directions to the location when the respective marker is tapped.

Comment: I would happy if I could open the phones native browser to view them, I did try and get the URL schemes working so that it would open in a maps app.

Comment: You can try opening the url in new tab and based on the settings of the user, native map app might open for the url. Check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks works on a desktop browser ill test it in app now and get back to you thanks

Comment: After testing in the app which the UI is built in a HTML layer it just opens to a full screen of the google maps so I can not navigate back into the UI of the app

Comment: Okay. I am not sure about the app but you can try looking for a non-fullscreen view of map in your ui.you can search on SO.